# laravel doc and docx validation issue

Tags: validation, laravel-4

I gave the validation rule like this

```
mimes:png,gif,jpeg,txt,pdf,doc,docx,zip,xml|max:1024
```

But when uploading doc file it shows error as :

```
The file1 must be a file of type: png, gif, jpeg, txt, pdf, doc, docx, zip, xml.
```

Earlier there was an issued occured for docx and i fixed it by adding zip to the validation rule. but now doc files are not uploading. did anyone knows how to solve this? is there any connection between the previous docx  error fix with this issue?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/33996572/2815945

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel 5.6 and greater

```
$request->validate([
    'file.*' => 'required|file|max:5000|mimes:docx,doc',
]);
```

Answer (score -2):

Mime type of a .doc file is "application/msword" according to https://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php .

Try with `mimes:application/msword`

Comment: i've already tried this sir `mimes:png,gif,jpeg,txt,pdf,doc,docx,zip,xml,application/msword|max:1024`. but didn't worked...