# laravel 5.1 error in validating doc docx type file

Tags: file, validation, mime-types, laravel-5.1, docx

Hi i am facing a docx type validation problem. I tried

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'resume'   => 'mimes:doc,pdf,docx'
        ]);
```

It will upload pdf file with no error but whenever i try to upload docx files it gives validation error 'must be a file of type: doc, pdf, docx'
any idea

Comment: What ist your result if you do a   dd($request->file('resume')->getMimeType());

Comment: it shows "application/zip surprised

Answer (score 24, accepted):

thanks solved it by allowing zip

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'resume'   => 'mimes:doc,pdf,docx,zip'
        ]);
```

this is because https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML

Answer (score 10):

In Laravel 5.6.3., I have solved this using `dot(.)` sign:

```
$request->validate([
    'file.*' => 'required|file|max:5000|mimes:pdf,docx,doc',
]);
```

Comment: As far as I can tell this allows fake files to pass validation. for example, renaming a .txt file to .pdf passes the validation, remove the dot * and it fails as expected.

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel 7+ to validate doc, docx you need to create mimes.php in config directory and add the following content,

config/mimes.php

```
<?php
 
return [
    'doc'  => array('application/msword', 'application/vnd.ms-office'),
    'docx' => array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 'application/zip'),
];
```