# Laravel input file validation

Tags: laravel, validation, pdf, upload, doc

I'm trying to make my validator working but for some reason it only accepts the pdf files. I want to make the validator works for all of them.

```
$filePathTemp = Input::file('cv');
$file = array('cv' => $filePathTemp);
$rules = array('cv' => 'mimes:doc,pdf,docx');
$validator = Validator::make($file, $rules);
```

Any idea why this solution isn't working?

Answer (score 2):

put this code

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'file' => 'required|max:10000|mimes:doc,docx,pdf' 

]);
```

and in config/mimes.php add the below mime types:

```
'doc'  => array('application/msword', 'application/vnd.ms-office'),
'docx' => array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 'application/zip'),
```

Hope this may help you!

Comment: I don't have this file mimes.php. Should I create it?

Comment: yes, you can use this link https://github.com/jasonlewis/laravel.com/blob/master/application/config/mimes.php

Comment: The cv must be a file of type: doc, docx, pdf. This is the message returned even if the uploaded file is a doc

Comment: Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33993874/laravel-5-1-error-in-validating-doc-docx-type-file

Comment: dd($request->file('resume')->getMimeType()); returns plain/text... it doesn't work adding zip to the mimes

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'cv'   => 'mimes:doc,pdf,docx'
        ]);
```

Hope this work for you!!!

Answer (score -1):

it worked adding the txt type to the other mimes